# Ubuntu thorugh a usb drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wanted learn and see how Ubuntu works. For that purpose i don't want to install it on my desktop but use it through a USB drive.

Can some share step by step details for creating a boot table Ubuntu environment through SU

Comment: Is Google broken?

Comment: The weekend is starting early...

Answer (score 1):

Found in about 15 seconds using Google. Look at that, right on the Ubuntu site where you have to download the install file:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install